# How to apply validation in Laravel generated registerController validator method

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, validation

I have a html form which has a field name "Signup With Email or Phone". This field will be used to register the user based on their email or phone (Whatever they provide). In Laravel I am using make:auth to generate login/signup files. RegisterControllr contains a function named "validator".

My question is how can I tweak the valiidator and create method so they check that whether the user entered the "email" or "phone" in the input field and then save them in database.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{

        return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:usersNew'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: What you've attempt so far?

Comment: @nmfzone I have found the solution. Just checked with $data['name'] conditions and compare it with a regex expression of phone numbers.